# Determinar el valor máximo entre 10 números

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hice el programa pero solo puedo ingresar dos valores (no los 10 que me pide) y sí me devuelve el mayor de esos dos.

```
def valmax (rango):
    nro=int(input("Ingrese un nro: "))
    mayor = nro
    for i in range(2, rango+1, 1):
        nro2=int(input("Ingrese otro nro: "))
        if mayor>nro2:
            return mayor
        else:
            mayor = nro2
            return mayor

    

r = int(input("ingrese la cantidad de digitos a ingresar: "))

print("El mayor de los digitos ingresados es el", valmax(r))
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te fue útil.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un fallo de lógica:

```
for i in range(2, rango + 1, 1):
    nro2 = int(input("Ingrese otro nro: "))
    if mayor > nro2:
        return mayor
    else:
        mayor = nro2
        return mayor
```

Tan pronto ingresas el segundo valor, ejecutas un `return` de la función.

Si te fijas, el `if` tiene un `return` en ambas ramas.

La forma correcta sería:

```
def valmax(rango):
    nro = int(input("Ingrese un nro: "))
    mayor = nro
    for i in range(rango - 1):
        nro2 = int(input("Ingrese otro nro: "))
        if mayor < nro2:
            mayor = nro2
    return mayor
```

Comment: Muchisimas Graciasss!! Me ayudo a sacarme algunas dudas que tenia